# Updating a graphic

Tags: java, timer

I'm creating a game where you use arrow keys to move your character(it's a square right now) across the screen to doge incoming objects, and I am using a timer to update the object coming across the screen, but when I click my start button to make the object move across the screen, it just freezes everything and doesn't reupdate and redraw it like I want to, any idea how to fix it?

This is my code, sorry, it may be slightly to neat and kind of spacy so hope you don't mind scrolling a bit. I hope you guys can help, i'm in highschool in my programming 2 class and my teacher doesn't work much with timers, thanks for the help!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;

    public class Game2v4 extends Frame implements ActionListener, KeyListener
    {
        int x = 100;
        int y = 100;
        Timer myTimer = new Timer(10,this);


            Panel southPanel = new Panel();
                Button startButton = new Button("Start");
                Button clearButton = new Button("Clear");

        public Game2v4()
        {
            addKeyListener(this);
            setFocusable(true);
            this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                southPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
                    add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                        southPanel.add(startButton);
                            startButton.addActionListener(this);
                        southPanel.add(clearButton);
                            clearButton.addActionListener(this);
addWindowListener
(
    new WindowAdapter()
    {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
);
        }

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
        {
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
            {
                y = y - 5;
                repaint();
            }

            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
            {
                y = y + 5;
                repaint();
            }

            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
            {
                x = x + 5;
                repaint();
            }

            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
            {
                x = x - 5;
                repaint();
            }

                while(x >= 400)
                {
                    x = 1;
                    repaint();
                }

                while(x <= -10)
                {
                    x = 400;
                    repaint();
                }

                while(y >= 400)
                {
                    y = 1;
                    repaint();
                }

                while(y <= 0)
                {
                    y = 400;
                    repaint();
                }


        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
        {

        }

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
        {

        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            Graphics g = getGraphics();
                if(e.getSource() == startButton)
                {
                    for(int i=250; i>0; i-=5)
                    {
                        g.drawRect(i,300,25,25);

                    }

                }
            this.requestFocus();
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            g.drawRect(x,y,25,25);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Game2v4 f = new Game2v4();
                f.setBounds(50,100,400,400);
                f.setTitle("Gamev4");
                f.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: welcome to SO. you can help us help you and format your code nicer. fix the indentation, otherwise the code is really hard to look through

Comment: I second what @LonelyNeuron suggests -- better code formatting means more readable code, means more folks who can understand your code and help you. As to your problem, your while loops are blocking the Swing event thread -- read [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for why this is an issue. Other problems -- your use of `getGraphics()` call on a component (don't do this), your use of the AWT and not the Swing library (or the JavaFX library)....